# Connecting two subnets

Tags: networking, routing

I have two subnets

```
A is 192.168.1.0/24, default gateway 192.168.1.1
B is 10.8.2.0/24, default gateway 10.8.2.1
```

and I want hosts on A to see hosts on B and vice versa.
I guess I'll need a physical communication between the gateways (really are home routers), then configure them with static routes. Any hint?

**Edit**

I don't understand why the question was closed. I specified I have 2 home users, I can add that they are in the same home. Don't think it's such a bad question

Comment: Read the [faq]. It should be very clear why it was closed.

Comment: I don't want to troll you, but really I cannot understand. I've written down all my requirements and my current configuration, I think it's enough to get a response back, something like *you need to buy this hardware and/or configure these things*. But I'm not an expert, so maybe I missed something. For example, what kind of information would you need to address this question?

Comment: You didn't read close enough. We don't do home gear. We don't do shopping recommendations. We are a site for **professionals** not enthusiasts or home users.

Answer (score 3):

> I want hosts on A to see hosts on B and vice versa. I guess I'll need a physical communication between the gateways (really are home routers), then configure them with static routes.

Yep.

> Any hint?

Considering you haven't given a drop of information about the hardware doing the routing, no. No hints.

Answer (score 0):

No hint, except if you go on Internet. The routers should drop the connections as they are non routed network classes.

Comment: Huh? This doesn't make sense. First, network classes don't exist any more. Second, it seems like he wants to route them internally on his LAN.

Comment: You are right, I should use the subnet term. But it doesn't change : he has to connect two home routers. How ? By Internet ?

Comment: I assume they're on the same internal network. The question is very unclear, though.

Comment: Yep, they are in the same home. They are two typical home routers with wifi extension. I asked if there is a way to let the two subnets communicate with each other

Answer (score 0):

If they are home routers in different homes with different Internet connections, you will not be able to do any routing between them; your only option would be to set up a VPN, if both devices support it *and* if both device can speak the same VPN dialect.

If they are in the same home and you want to connect them, then it depends on the specific rouers you are using; some routers have additional Ethernet ports you can use for this, but most of them only have the LAN and WAN (be it DSL, cable or anything else) interfaces.

It's not possible to say anything more without additional details about your setup.

Comment: The routers are typical wifi home routers. They have 4-5 LAN ports and the DSL. When I connect them via LAN and they are on the same subnet everything works fine. What happens if I connect them and they are on different subnets?

Comment: You can't connect them using their LAN ports if they are on different subnets. You need to set up routing between them, but in order to do that, you should use routers that can do... well... *routing*.

Comment: So it's impossible with the current hardware. I'd need a _special_ _router_ :P can you tell me how this router is called? Or linking a sample product? Just for educative purposes, I was only wondering if something like that could even be possible

Comment: It *is* possible (that's what routers are for...), but not with home DSL routers, usually. I know for sure Cisco routers, even low-end ones (like my 877) can do this with some configuration, but usually a cheap home router can only do LAN/WAN routing and maybe some VPN, not much else.

Comment: But is it a hardware lack or a software one? I mean, _what_ would you do with your router?